# How to code based clicking of Ajax links with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i implement a code for auto-clicking

```
<a href="#" class="link">test</a>
```

type links?

```
$('a.link').click();
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Now i figured out. This is working:

```
$('a.l_like').each(function(index) {
    $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.link').click(function(){
   // you jquery ajax code
});
```

you can then go like

```
$('someotherelement').click(function(){
    $('a.link').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for?